# Create a chess board in Flex 4.6

Tags: apache-flex, flash-builder

I'm starting a new project in Flash Builder 4.6 and need some advices before going in one direction instead of the right one.

Basically, my application in Flash Builder is for mobile devices and tablets, so I need to know how could I create a chess board that fix exactly the width of any device. I do not know how could i do it exactly in Flex.

Could anyone give an idea or supply an example i could use?

Thanks.

Comment: Generically; based on the amount of screen space available to the app; just write code to size and position your elements on the screen.  In a Flex Component you can do the size and position code inside of updateDisplayList() method; and the arguments to updateDisplayList() are your height and width.  Did you have a specific question?  have you tried anything?  I'm unclear exactly what info you're after.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use a TileGroup/TileLayout with 100% height and width? You then set the rowHeight to be {this.height / ROWS} (ROWS being however many rows there are on a Chessboard) and doing the same for columnWidth. You could even use the horizontalGap and verticalGap properties to show through to a black background that could be used as separators between each box (though you would have to account for this in your rowHeight and columnWidth calculations, obviously)

I would populate the screen via AS3, as opposed to Flex. Something like this is what I have in mind.

```
var columnCount:int = 0;
var rowCount:int = 0;
var boxes:int = 64; //however many boxes on a chess board goes here
for ( var i:Number = 0; i < boxes; i+ ){
    var rect:Rect = new Rect();
    var color:SolidColor;
    rect.percentHeight = 100;
    rect.percentWidth = 100;
    rect.name = i.toString(); //this will make it easier to keep track of which box is which later on
    if ( rowCount % 2 == 1 ) {
        if ( i % 2 == 1 ) color = 0x000000;
        else color = 0xffffff;
    }
    else {
        if ( i % 2 == 1 ) color = 0xffffff;
        else color = 0x000000;
    }
    this.rect.fill = color;
    this.tileGroup.addElement(rect);

    if ( columnCount == 7 ) {
        columnCount = 0;
        rowCount++;
    }
    else {
        columnCount++;
    }
}
```

That is completely off the top of my head and untested, so I am sure there is an error or two, but you get the idea of how it would work.

**EDIT**: As an afterthought, you could probably do the colors 100% mathematically without using rowCount/columnCount vars, though it is probably much much easier to do so.